# SCSS Undefined variable: "$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings" while precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I am using active_admin for my rails project. ActiveAdmin depends on `bourbon` gem. When I run `rake assets:precompile`, I am getting this below error.

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings".
/home/selvamani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bourbon-4.3.4/app/assets/stylesheets/addons/_buttons.scss:56
```

I have declared `$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings: false;` at top of my application.css.scss file. But no luck.

How to declared or override SCSS variable for a dependencies gem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try: $output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings: false !default;

Comment: @Sajin Yeah, I did. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off the warnings, you can add this code in your main Sass-file, before importing Bourbon and other Sass files:
`$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings: false !default;`.

For example:
`app/assets/stylesheets/app.scss`

```
$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings: false !default;

@import "bourbon";
```